# Isolated Type 3 Compensator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, feedback, full-bridge, compensation

I'm trying to build a full bridge dc-dc converter and planning to apply a type 3 compensator(voltage mode). When I check the isolated feedback type 3, I've read some comments indicate that it's hard to apply in practice. Than I decided to do it in another way but I'm not sure if it's going to work or not.

I'm planning to put the pwm IC on secondary side so there will be no need for isolating the feedback, and feed the IC from input voltage through an isolated dc-dc module, and use a isolated gate driver, then I can apply non isolated type 3 compensation but still maintain the isolation on circuit.

Here is my circuit plan:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fch1kS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Question is: Will it work?

(output voltage is 350V so the pwm IC will be on same ground with a 350V output)

Complete Circuit:

(component name and values are random)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj7kDI.png)</sup>

Comment: While the block diagram helps, it leaves too many details unclear. I know your design is incomplete, but could you offer a tentative schematic for evaluation?

Comment: It boils down to which is the weakest link? Is it (a) an isolated feedback signal or (b) an isolated gate drive signal.

Comment: Using a transformer as voltage feedback would imply that you have only a certain range of invertrer's output fundamental frequency. It is sometimes easier to use an isolated ADC.

Comment: I'm going to prepare detailed sch quickly

Comment: Circuit is added to post.

Comment: (a) a single isolated input signal (that could also be on/off) or (b) 4 opto-isolated drivers that maintain the ability to not degrade anti-shoot-through timing despite optos being a little flaky on rise and fall times. It's (a) for me everytime.

Comment: @Andyaka yes you're right but isolating the type 3 compensator feedback is quite hard for me, I don't know how to calculate components for isolated feedback. I have made all calculations for non-isolated type 3 but when it comes to isolating the type 3, it confuses my mind, I can't understand the calculations (tl431 + optocoupler)

Comment: I don't see a reason why an optoisolated type 3 would not give good results with properly-characterized components, i.e. the optocoupler itself. Otherwise, it is very common in high-power converters to keep the PWM and regulation in the secondary side then transmit the driving pulses to directly drive the transistors with a transformer. An auxiliary power supply then cranks the whole thing by providing power to the sec. side PWM control. See some of the many examples in PC silver boxes [here](http://danyk.cz/s_atx_en.html) where this is very common with 2-SW forwards or LLCs.

Comment: The TL431 does not lend itself well to designing a type 3 with an optocoupler because you cannot easily split the second pole-zero pair as you wish. A better option is to ac-isolate the fast lane via a simple Zener-based regulator. This is all described in a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf) I gave in 2010 (see slide 122). Isolated type 3 are very common for high-crossover dc-dc modules operated in voltage-mode control.

Comment: I've even seen designs where the pulses were coupled to the primary side through PCB transformers - coiled traces stacked on top of each other. Calculations will only go so far; even a failed prototype will be a valuable learning experience.